# In PHP, 0 (int, zero) is equal to "first" or "last" (strings)?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I'm confused by something I just ran into in a script I was working on.  I had the following:

```
function getPart($part)
{
    $array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    if ($part == 'first') $part = 0;
    if ($part == 'last') $part = count($array) - 1;
    if (isset($array[$part])) return $array[$part];
    return false;
}

$position = 0;
echo getPart($position);
```

So, if I were to try the string "first", I should get "a" as the output.  With the string "last" I should get "c" and so on.  When I run the script above, with PHP 5.3, I get "c" ...

Confused, I ran a quick test ...

```
var_dump(0 == 'first');
var_dump(0 == 'last');
```

Both return `TRUE` ... **WHY???**  I am so confused by this behavior!

Comment: Enter the world of weak typing. `'first' == 0 ` and `0 == 'last'` but `'first' != 'last'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try to compare a string to a number, PHP will try to convert the string to a number. In this case, it fails to do so, since PHP can't convert *"first"* or *"last"* into a number, so it simply converts it to zero. This makes the check `0 == 0`, which is, of course, true. Use the identity operator, `===`, if you want PHP to not attempt to convert anything (so, the two operands must have the same value and be of the same type).

Comment: I am so used to comparing a string "1" and an integer 1 that this didn't cross my mind.  One of the down sides to a weakly typed language.

Answer (score 3):

Check out `(int) 'first'`. That is essentially what PHP is doing to the right hand operand.

PHP will coerce operand types when not using the strict equality comparison operator (`===`) between two operands of different types.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is weakly typed. What's happening there is it's trying to convert `"first"` to a number. It fails, and returns zero. It now has two numbers: zero and zero. To make it not try to convert the types, use `===` rather than `==`.

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a bit strange in that it treats a string in numeric comparison as 0. You can force string comparison by quoting the variables:

```
function getPart($part)
{
    $array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    if ("$part" == 'first') $part = 0;
    if ("$part" == 'last') $part = count($array) - 1;
    if (isset($array[$part])) return $array[$part];
    return false;
}
```